# Alternative to the currently unmaintained Mozilla Litmus test management tool?

Tags: testing, open-source

We are currently in a desperate need for some manual test management tool. Currently we are using Excel which is unexciting at the very least.

Essentially, [litmus](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Litmus) is what we need, however it's a pain to install, tailored to Mozilla, buggy and also hasn't been actively developed for a couple of years now.

Can you recommend an open-source alternative?

**EDIT:** Don't nail me on the proper name on this testing, it's a mixture of smoke, regression and acceptance testing and it's mostly manual for now. We have yet to develop our automated tests, until then we need a proper test definition to check our releases against.

Answer (score 0):

[Putsmail](http://putsmail.com) by Pablo Cantero has just been released.

The source code is on GitHub.

It's still at an early stage though.

Comment: How's that a test management tool?

Comment: Sorry, my link is relevant only as an alternative to http://litmus.com/ which has nothing to do with Mozilla.
I guess people finding this question on SO may either be looking for Mozilla's litmus or the one I was referring to.

Comment: Could be. The question is now five years old, and if I remember correctly, Litmus the e-mail testing tool is at most a couple of years old. Anyway, I suppose the question will be closed soon, so never mind.